# What is the Mathematical equation for [if(value > 10) value = 10]?

Tags: math

This is a very simple problem to do in a program but I cant seem to be able to break it down into a mathematical equation.

```
if(value > 10)
    value = 10;
else
    value = value;
```

what would this mathematical equation look like?

Answer (score 5):

```
min(value,10)
```

gives the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`x*(1 - H(x-10)) + 10*H(x-10)`

Where H(x) is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)